# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.browserlaunchers.DoNotUseProxyPac

Tags: java, maven, selenium

I am trying to execute an maven test project and i am getting the following error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:org.openqa.selenium.browserlaunchers.DoNotUseProxyPac
```

It is able to launch the browser. but not able to open the URL.

Following is the Simple selenium script that is written to open google.com

```
public static String Sample()
    {
        APPLICATION_LOGS.info(" Executing Sample Keyword");
        try {
            WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();  
            System.out.println("Hello Google...");  
            driver.get("http://google.com");    
            result = "Navigated to URL google.com ";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "Pass";
    }
```

Below is the error I am getting on console:-

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/openqa/selenium/browserlaunchers/DoNotUseProxyPac     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonToBeanConverter.convert(JsonToBeanConverter.java:123)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonToBeanConverter.convert(JsonToBeanConverter.java:42)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.decode(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:62)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.createResponse(HttpCommandExecutor.java:312)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:189)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.execute(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:165)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver$LazyCommandExecutor.execute(FirefoxDriver.java:362)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:572)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:240)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:126)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:191)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:182)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:95)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are missing one of the required dependency in your class path, this exception occurs.

According to the [this documentation](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/index.html?org/openqa/selenium/browserlaunchers/DoNotUseProxyPac.html), you need to add following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openqa.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-rc</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-20081010.060147</version>
</dependency>
```